# Sass - SyntaxError: Not a valid CSS value

Tags: css, sass, precompile

This is my Sass file:

```
\:root
    @each $name, $color in $colors
        @if type-of($color) == "map"
            @each $subname, $subsize in $color
                --color-#{$name}-#{$subname}: #{$subsize}
        @elseif type-of($color) == "number"
            --color-#{$name}: #{$color}
```

`$colors` looks like this:

```
$colors: (
    accent: (
        darker: #2840d0,
        dark: #2d5ee8,
        base: #2d81e8,
        light: #76b8f0,
        lighter: #b6e1f9
    )
);
```

Now this is the error I am getting:

> Sass::SyntaxError: (darker: #2840d0, dark: #2d5ee8, base: #2d81e8, light: #76b8f0, lighter: #b6e1f9) isn't a valid CSS value.

It refers to `--color-#{$name}: #{$color}`.

Comment: What version of sass are you using?

Comment: @miir .  `3.5.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some testing and found that the `@elseif` is incorrect, it should be `@else if` with a space between `else` and `if`.

Some additional notes -- the quotes around the type are not necessary. Both of these will work:

`type-of($color) == "map"` and `type-of($color) == map`

Additionally, colors are their own type in sass, so the last condition may not work as desired and you may want to change it:

`@else if type-of($color) == "number"` to `@else if type-of($color) == color`